# Wrong Dates when Downloading Data in Loop through investpy

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm trying to debug some strange behaviour in some code I was using to download data through the investpy API (investing.com).

What happens is that I initially downloaded data from 2000 onwards but changed the start date to 2007 to avoid NaNs. I'm running the data through a for loop for all the series I'd like to download. For some reason doing that doesn't change the start date and I do not understand why.

To avoid misunderstandings: My question is not about how to cut-off the missing observations, that's easy. I'm trying to understand what causes this as I want to avoid another bug that I might be missing.

Thanks for the help!

Code:

```
import investpy
import pandas as pd
maturities=['3M','6M','1Y','2Y','3Y','4Y','5Y','6Y','7Y','8Y','9Y','Germany 10-Year','20Y','30Y']
eu = list()
for x in maturities:
    search_result = investpy.search_quotes(text=x, products=['bonds'],
                                       countries=['germany'], n_results=1)
    historical_data = search_result.retrieve_historical_data(from_date='04/01/2007', to_date='23/07/2021')
    eu.append(historical_data.Close)
eu=pd.concat(eu, axis=1)
eu.columns=maturities
eu=eu.reindex(date).fillna(method='ffill')
eu=eu.add_prefix('eu_')
eu = eu.rename(columns={'eu_Germany 10-Year': 'eu_10Y'})
eu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question here for those who end up with similar issues (due to lazy/sloppy code style). I forgot copying over one important line that explains it, here is the complete code:

```
maturities=['3M','6M','1Y','2Y','3Y','4Y','5Y','6Y','7Y','8Y','9Y','Germany 10-Year','20Y','30Y']
eu = list()
date=pd.date_range('2007-01-04', '2021-07-23')
for x in maturities:
    search_result = investpy.search_quotes(text=x, products=['bonds'],
                                       countries=['germany'], n_results=1)
    historical_data = search_result.retrieve_historical_data(from_date='04/01/2007', to_date='23/07/2021')
    eu.append(historical_data.Close)
eu=pd.concat(eu, axis=1)
eu.columns=maturities
eu=eu.reindex(date).fillna(method='ffill')
eu=eu.add_prefix('eu_')
eu = eu.rename(columns={'eu_Germany 10-Year': 'eu_10Y'})
eu
```

In the top bit (as you'd guess) I still had the following line stored:

```
date=pd.date_range('2000-01-04', '2021-07-23')
```

This forced re-indexation of dates from 2000 on, creating NaNs for all days that followed until the start date I chose in the query.